# webpage cannot be accessed from other computer

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I'm a newbie in httpd and my problem is I cannot access my webpage from other computer.

What I am trying to do is deploying with minimal httpd.conf file with following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZioHruINOA.

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf is

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
User apache
Group apache
ServerName www.example.com
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error.log
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
DirectoryIndex index.html
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

after I run command

```
sudo apachectl start
w3m 172.31.30.53
```

I can see the desired webpage(/var/www/html/index.html)

However, running command

```
w3m 172.31.30.53
```

on other computer's terminal does not work.

Thank you in advance.

> **edit1:**

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW       0.0.0.0
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

> **edit2:**

```
/etc/apache2$ nmap 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-05-20 21:31 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00019s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.91 seconds
```

Comment: And "does not work" means what _exactly_ ? What error do you get?

Comment: Thanks, arkascha. Terminal says Opening socket... and freezes.

Comment: Does it terminate after more than 30 seconds claiming a timeout? Or does it hang forever?

Comment: after around a minute it says, w3m: Can't load 172.31.24.168.

Comment: OK, that typically means that you run into a timeout. So most likely the network connection is blocked by either a routing issue or, much more likely, a firewall blocking access to the servers port.

Comment: I would suggest to try and replace `Listen 0.0.0.0:80` by `Listen 172.31.24.168:80` in your httpd.conf

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me that you are trying to run your webserver on a Linux machine. If you want to access your webpages from other computers, you might want to check your firewall settings. Accessing locally should work, but depending on your distro, you'll have to allow access. On Ubuntu you'll have to check `ufw`.

**EDIT 1:**

Try `nmap` from another machine. This way you can see what ports are available. Example: `nmap yourmachine`

Comment: Thanks Socrate. Edit1 in my original posting is the result of ufw.

Comment: @HeejunChoi Can you try `nmap yourmachine` from another Linux machine in the same network and post the result as `EDIT 2`?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure yourmachine is 127.0.0.1 but this is what I got.

Comment: @HeejunChoi That's your localhost. You have to do the `nmap` from another machine than the one you have your server on.